# Alfresco community edition-5.1.x workflow form Administrator whats to add wherever have drop-down fields add more values via front-end

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco community edition-5.1.x ,I have created workflow activiti using kick-start after deployed alfresco workflow activti is working successfully. Administrator whats to add wherever have drop-down fields add more values via front-end without restart alfresco service is this possible ? help me out.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain more precisely what you want ?

Comment: As per Akah, I would suggest you need to flesh out this question some more. However, at least when I was last using Alfresco Share (4.0), the workflow models are only loaded as part of tomcat's initialization, so I would expect any changes to the model would require a restart.

Comment: Alfresco latest version have model manager in administrator menu is this help to create custom field to link with workflow model is this possible?

Comment: Could well be, but I wouldn't have a clue without re-aquainting myself. You might do well to ask over at the afresco forums - it's not the most ubiquitous software package so I've had trouble finding answers here on SO before, but they have a relatively active community. Of course if you did find an answer there I'd suggest bringing it back over to SO here and self-answering with it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestions